# $a^k \mid a^\ell \Leftrightarrow k\leq \ell$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

What would be the formal argument for showing the following statements: Let $a\geq 2$ be an integer, then:

**$(i)$** $a^k \mid a^\ell$ if and only if $k\leq \ell$.

**$(ii)$** if $a^k | a^\ell m$ and $a\not \mid m$ then $k\leq \ell$.

**Obs:** Maybe some additional hypothesis on $a$ must be added.

Thanks

Comment: What is $b$? Can't $a$ be 1 or 0 or -1?

Comment: Sorry, I missed that =)

Comment: I added $a\geq 2$ for it is the case I'll need..

Comment: Consider the prime factorisation of $a$ (and $m$ for the second).

Answer (score 2):

For the first part (this works backwards, too):
$$
a^k \mid a^{\ell} \\
\implies a^{\ell} = na^k \\
\implies \frac{a^{\ell}}{a^k} = n \\
\implies a^{\ell-k} = n \\
\because a \geq 2, n \geq 1 \\
\therefore {\ell} - k \geq 0
$$

For the second part, let's assume $k \gt \ell$. Then:
$$
\begin{align*}
a^{\ell}m &= na^k \\
&= na^{k - \ell}a^{\ell} \\
\implies m &= na^{k - \ell} \\
&= (na^{k - \ell -1})a \\
\implies a &\mid m
\end{align*}
$$
Obviously, $a \mid m$ contradicts $a \nmid m$ and so our initial assumption that $k \gt \ell$ is wrong. So $k \leq \ell$. Thanks to @PtF for this solution!

Comment: For the second part, $x\mid yz$ and $x\nmid z$ does not (generally) imply $x\mid y$. It holds if $\gcd(x,z) = 1$, but $\gcd(a,m) = 1$ is not given here. You need a different argument.

Comment: As to the second part we may do by contradiction: If $k>\ell$ then $a^\ell m=n a^{k-\ell} a^\ell$ implies $m= (na^{k-\ell-1}) a$ so that $a|m$, a contradiction, right @DanielFischer?

Comment: I've fixed it, I hope... is this correct now?

Comment: Not yet fixed, it is possible that $\gcd (a^k,p_i^{n_i}) > 1$ for all $i$ (it is possible that a prime divides $a$ if and only if it divides $m$, even). What @PtF wrote in his/her comment is one possible fix.

Comment: Okay, thanks. @PtF, I'm using your solution.